# Type Mismatch Run Time Error '13'

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I have searched everywhere for an answer to this issue and I am fairly new to VBA so I hope you can help.  Below is the code.

```
If [e19].Value + [g19].Value = [c19].Value Then
[l19].Value = "Yes"
ElseIf [e19].Value = "N/A" Then
[l19].Value = "N/A"
**ElseIf Range("i18:i21, l18").Value = "{a}" Then**
l19.Value = "{b}"
```

The code wrapped in ** is where I am having my issue.  Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: You can't check the Value of a multi-area range like that.  What do you want to test?  Whether any value in that range is "a", or whether all values are "a"?

Comment: Here is a link [**How to debug VBA code**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1ARYg4ZJBA)

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a range with a specific value.. You could take each cell inside a 'For Each xxx In Range.Cells...Next' statement to proceed to the comparison for each value inside the range, but note that each cell is compared individually, in turn. This code should work this way:

```
Sub zo()
If [e19].Value + [g19].Value = [c19].Value Then
    [l19].Value = "Yes"
ElseIf [e19].Value = "N/A" Then
    [l19].Value = "N/A"
Else
    For Each cell In Range("i18:i21, l18")
        If cell.Value = "{a}" Then
            [l19].Value = "{b}"
        End If
    Next
End If
End Sub
```